# Можно ли в Python получить размер объекта по его id?

Tags: python, struct, ctypes, sizeof

Задание такое: написать функцию, которая по id объекта возвращает сам объект. Нельзя пользоваться ctypes.cast, _ctypes, gc, locals, globals и т.д., рекомендуется использовать struct и ctypes.
Например, для объекта типа int я пишу следующее:

```
struct.unpack("LLli", ctypes.string_at(id_of_object, 28))
```

если я знаю, что размер int не превышает 28 байт. Но int может быть любого размера. Могу ли я для этого способа как-то получить в Python размер самого объекта по его id? Или в этой задаче нужно использовать вообще какие-то другие функции?

Answer (score 2):

Любой объект начинается с счетчика ссылок и ссылки на тип. Моя проблема решается так: сначала с помощью ctypes.string_at получаем ссылку на тип, будет лежать в `tuple` второй:

```
struct.unpack("LL", ctypes.string_at(object_id, 16))
```

Затем, например, в случае типа `int` получаем количество "кусочков", будет лежать третьим в `tuple`:

```
info = struct.unpack("LLl", ctypes.string_at(object_id, 24))
```

И, наконец, получаем все число:

```
num_of_pieces = abs(info[2])
size_of_obj = 24 + 4 * num_of_pieces
type_string = "i" * num_of_pieces
number = struct.unpack("LLl" + type_string, ctypes.string_at(object_id, size_of_obj))
i = 0
res = 0
for n in number[3:]:
    res += n * (2 ** 30) ** i
    i += 1
return res if info[2] > 0 else -res
```

С другими типами все будет лежать немного иначе, там надо разбираться с каждым случаем отдельно.